# Registering keystrokes using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use pygame to register keystrokes by pulling them from the event queue. I'm able to retrieve the key, but I cannot extract it from the rest of the information that follows. This is how it looks:

```
[<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': 'r', 'key': 114, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 19})>]
```

I have tried treating it like a string, list, tuple, and dictionary, but nothing yields anything useful.

This is the code I used to get information from the event queue:

```
def get_key():
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        key_list.append(event)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the events or keystrokes?

Comment: I'm trying to create a typing game, but it looks like this wont be the best way to record keystrokes after all. It will disregard keystrokes if you type to fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a Pygame [`EventType`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.EventType) object.

According to the Pygame [documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.EventType) on the subject, you can access its attributes via the `__dict__` member.

Here's an example (`event.__dict__` is a `dict` object):

```
>>> event.__dict__['key']
114
>>> event.__dict__['mod']
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to access the attributes directly:

```
In [1]: import pygame

In [2]: pygame.init()
Out[2]: (6, 0)

In [3]: event = pygame.event.poll()

In [4]: event
Out[4]: <Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 0, 'key': 310, 'unicode': u'', 'mod': 0})>

In [5]: event.key
Out[5]: 310
```

See this [pygame example](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40b%40r%40BrickPi_Python-HEAD%40Project_Examples%40Shooter_pygame.py/27/pygame.event.poll/python).

What you posted looks more like a *list* of events than a single event. Are you sure you're using `pygame.event.poll` and not `pygame.event.get`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need the `unicode` attribute of the event. Also, use `pygame.event.get()` instead of `poll` to get all keystrokes.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        key_list.append(event.unicode)
```

Comment: Regarding the missed keystrokes, better post another question.